# Format double in C#

Tags: c#

I have a double value. I want to format this value in the format of x.yz. How do I do this? I keep getting digits truncated. Can someone tell me how to do this in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: `myDouble.ToString("0.00");`?

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example, plus check the questions linked on the right of the page under "Related".

Comment: @Jeff M - Thanks! I thought zeros meant a zero would be shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using format strings is explained in:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

For example, try:

- `(0.56789).ToString("F2")`
- `(0.56789).ToString("0.00")`.

Note that the resulting value is NOT truncated, but rounded in both cases, resulting in `"0.57"`.

Answer (score 17):

**Digits after decimal point**

This example formats double to string with fixed number of decimal places. For two decimal places use pattern „0.00“. If a float number has less decimal places, the rest digits on the right will be zeroes. If it has more decimal places, the number will be rounded.

```
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

Next example formats double to string with floating number of decimal places. E.g. for maximal two decimal places use pattern „0.##“.

```
// max. two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```

**Digits before decimal point**

If you want a float number to have any minimal number of digits before decimal point use N-times zero before decimal point. E.g. pattern „00.0“ formats a float number to string with at least two digits before decimal point and one digit after that.

```
// at least two digits before decimal point
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 123.4567);      // "123.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 23.4567);       // "23.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", 3.4567);        // "03.5"
String.Format("{0:00.0}", -3.4567);       // "-03.5"
```

**Thousands separator**

To format double to string with use of thousands separator use zero and comma separator before an usual float formatting pattern, e.g. pattern „0,0.0“ formats the number to use thousands separators and to have one decimal place.

```
String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 12345.67);     // "12,345.7"
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 12345.67);       // "12,346"
```

**Zero**

Float numbers between zero and one can be formatted in two ways, with or without leading zero before decimal point. To format number without a leading zero use # before point. For example „#.0“ formats number to have one decimal place and zero to N digits before decimal point (e.g. „.5“ or „123.5“).

Following code shows how can be formatted a zero (of double type).

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}", 0.0);            // "0.0"
String.Format("{0:0.#}", 0.0);            // "0"
String.Format("{0:#.0}", 0.0);            // ".0"
String.Format("{0:#.#}", 0.0);            // ""
```

**Align numbers with spaces**

To align float number to the right use comma „,“ option before the colon. Type comma followed by a number of spaces, e.g. „0,10:0.0“ (this can be used only in String.Format method, not in double.ToString method). To align numbers to the left use negative number of spaces.

```
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", 123.4567);    // "     123.5"
String.Format("{0,-10:0.0}", 123.4567);   // "123.5     "
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", -123.4567);   // "    -123.5"
String.Format("{0,-10:0.0}", -123.4567);  // "-123.5    "
```

**Custom formatting for negative numbers and zero**

If you need to use custom format for negative float numbers or zero, use semicolon separator „;“ to split pattern to three sections. The first section formats positive numbers, the second section formats negative numbers and the third section formats zero. If you omit the last section, zero will be formatted using the first section.

```
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", 123.4567);   // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", -123.4567);  // "minus 123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00;minus 0.00;zero}", 0.0);        // "zero"
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}",yourdouble);
```

And maybe you'll find useful stick a paper with this http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf somewhere in your office

Answer (score 2):

Tried something like this, using ToString?

```
doubleNumber = -1898300.1937;
Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
// Displays -1898300.19
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Math.Round Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx)

```
Math.Round(yourdouble, 2)
```

You can also specify the rounding rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
number.ToString("0.00");
```

Also take a look at [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)