# Silverlight 4 StringFormat for double without decimals in XAML

Tags: string, silverlight, xaml, format, double

I have a TextBlock which value will be a double and I am using tihs code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt_MyCurrentValue"
           Text="{Binding ElementName=MyCtrlDashboardTextualValue,
                          Path=CurrentValue,
                          StringFormat=\{0:n2\}}"
```

But this code is always showing 2 decimals, even when the number has no decimals.

Is there a way to specify a StringFormat in order to use as minimum decimal places as possible?

Edit:

The solution is: **0.##** (Found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916292/383129)

The code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt_MyCurrentValue"
           Text="{Binding ElementName=MyCtrlDashboardTextualValue,
                          Path=CurrentValue,
                          StringFormat=\{0:0.##\}}"
```

Comment: If you found the answer please post it as an answer rather than editing your question. That fits the Stack Overflow Q&A model.

Comment: Ok, but:
Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Hmm - didn't realise it suggested editing the question.