# What is the best mask for decimal digits?

Tags: c#

I want to create a `TextBox` for decimal digits with this pattern:

```
1/23
12/34
12/323
```

The integer part is less than 2 and the double part is less than 3.

Comment: What integer part? What double part?

Comment: Is 'integer part' the bit before the `/` and 'double part' the bit after?

Comment: @George Duckett: Only one of the "bit before" the `/` satisfy "less than `2`" and none of the "bit after" the `/` satisfy "less than `3`".

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: @RoyDictus, "What is the best mask for decimal digits?"

Comment: @Jason: I'm also assuming "less than" should be "less than or equal to" (and refers to number of characters). Bit of a stretch I admit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format double in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916240/format-double-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @George Duckett: Well, that is certainly a definition that matches the given data. It's unfortunate we have to work so hard to figure out what the OP *might* mean.

Comment: @BlotClock thie integer part is digits before / and decimal part is digits after /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a regular expression.  Something like:

```
Regex.IsMatch("133/33", @"^\d{1,2}(\/\d{1,3})?$");
```

This should return true if the whole part of the number being 1 to 2 digits in length and the decimal part is optional, but if present should be no greater than 3 digits in length.

Or if the decimal part isn't optional:

```
Regex.IsMatch("133/33", @"^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,3}$");
```

(The "133/33" is an example number as a string)