# Format a string using binding to format currency with no decimal places

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking to bind data in my datagrid to look like

*$1,200*

however, I have not found a way to do this.

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916240/format-double-in-c-sharp/4916292#4916292) which gives me

*1,200* using `{0:0,0}`

but it does not have a dollar sign in front.

What do I need to use to accomplish this using the StringFormat member of a binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your need correctly, you can just use the [`"C"` formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx). It's the second one listed in the examples that links to.

```
decimal a = 1200;

return a.ToString("C"); // or string.Format("{0:C}", a);
```

You can also use `"C0"` if you, in fact, don't want any decimal places represented.

The major advantage of this over any custom format string is that this adjusts itself to culture variations client-side.

Comment: ah thanks I was just about to make a comment that I didn't want decimal places...

Comment: @jharr100 I noticed that right after I posted it, then I wanted to double-check that it worked before I said anything. :)